# Python Turtle Graphics Tic - Tac - Toe Game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tic-tac-toe, python-turtle

I have been working on a Tic - Tac - Toe project for the past few days using only Turtle Graphics. I need to have 3 options for playing; User vs. User, User vs. Computer, and Computer vs. Computer. So far, User vs. User seems to be working fine. I can't seem to get the random.choice() to work correctly for User vs. Computer. It either won't show the 'O' that its supposed to draw, or draws over another shape when it's not supposed to. I haven't started on the Computer vs. Computer part just yet. Below is my code:

```
import time
import turtle
import random

screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle.pendown()
turn = 'x'

def setup_game():
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.speed(0)
  turtle.goto(-200 ,200) 
  turtle.forward(100)
  turtle.pendown()
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(300)
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.right(-90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  turtle.right(-90)
  turtle.pendown()
  turtle.forward(300)
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.goto(-200, 200)
  turtle.right(180)
  turtle.forward(100)
  turtle.right(-90)
  turtle.pendown()
  turtle.forward(300)
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.forward(100)
  turtle.right(90)
  turtle.pendown()
  turtle.forward(300)

def draw_x (location):
  if location == 0:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-175,175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-125,125)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-125, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-175, 125)

  elif location == 1:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-75,175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-25,125)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-25, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-75, 125)

  elif location == 2:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto( 25,175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto( 75,125)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(75, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(25, 125)

  elif location == 3:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-175, 75 )
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-125,25)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-125, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-175, 25)

  elif location == 4:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-75,75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-25,25)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-25, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-75, 25)

  elif location == 5:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(25,75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(75,25)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(75, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(25, 25)

  elif location == 6:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-175,-25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-125, -75)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-125,-25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-175, -75)

  elif location == 7:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-75,-25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-25,-75)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-25, -25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-75, -75)

  elif location == 8:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(25,-25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(75,-75)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(75, -25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(25, -75)

# def draw_o(location): 
def draw_o (location):
  if location == 0:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-150, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 1:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-50, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 2:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto( 50, 175)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 3:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-150, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 4:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-50, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 5:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(50, 75)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 6:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-150 ,-25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 7:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-50, -25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

  if location == 8:
    turtle.speed(2.5)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(50, -25)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)

def win_check():
    # horizontal check
    for i in range(0, 9, 3):
        if (board[i] == board[i + 1] == board[i + 2]):
            return True

    # vertical check
    for i in range(3):
        if (board[i] == board[i + 3] == board[i + 6]):
            return True

    # diagonal check
    if ((board[0] == board[4] == board[8]) or (board[2] == board[4] == board[6])):
        return True

# user vs computer      
def computer_move (move):

  global board, turn, game, random

  if board[move] >= 0 and board[move] <= 8:
    board[move] = turn
    print ("heres board", board)

    if turn == 'o':
      move = random.choice(board)
      draw_o(move)
      if (win_check()):
        game = 'over'
      turn = 'x'

    elif turn == 'x':
      draw_x(move)
      if (win_check()):
        game = 'over'
      turn = 'o'  

def which_square (x,y):

  """This function will convert the xy coordinate into squares of the tic tac toe board 
  [ 0 | 1 | 2 ]
  [ 3 | 4 | 5 ]
  [ 6 | 7 | 8 ]
  """

  global game

  if game == 'over':
    return None

  # check which square does the xy coordinate belongs to
  # if not((x < -200) or (x > 100)) or ((y > 200) or (y <-100)):
  if y <= 200 and y >= 100:
    if x >= 0:
      move = 2 
    elif x >= -100:
      move = 1 
    elif x >= -200:
      move = 0 

  elif y < 100 and y >=0:
    if x >= 0:
      move = 5 
    elif x >= -100:
      move = 4
    elif x >= -200:
      move = 3

  elif y <0 and y >= -100:
    if x >= 0:
      move = 8
    elif x >= -100:
      move = 7
    elif x >= -200:
      move = 6 

  # draws 
  computer_move(move)

setup_game()

game = 'not over'
move = None
board = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


#Everytime this function is called, it passes xy coordinate into a function inside the parathensis.
screen.onscreenclick(which_square)

print('User 1, please click where you want to go. (You may have to click twice.)')

turtle.done()
```

I have included a print function to show the choice that the user and computer makes, but it doesn't always draw the 'O' from the computer, and sometimes overlaps the 'X' even though the print does not show it overlapping, and it doesn't allow overlaps.

Also, I am somewhat new to python, only working with it for the past couple months.

Any help with this would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Can you reduce this code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? It's a lot of code to sift through and I can't seem to replicate the `random.choice` error you're getting.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's updated to a MCVE now, only using the essentials to work.

Comment: Can you fix some things:
`screen = turtle.Screen()`
`turtle.pendown()`

Also, the game window disappears before you can click on it (python3.5)

Comment: I'm sorry, accidentally deleted parts when reducing it. It should work fine now.